# A continuous function whose Fourier Series diverges

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, divergent-series

I have read several times that there exist many continuous functions whose Fourier series diverge at some points (sometimes even on a dense subset of the domain!). I tried to find an explicit example of them and the closest thing I found is [This example by Fejer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260322/drawing-a-continuous-function-with-divergent-fourier-series-at-x-0), a link from MSE. According to a comment responding to the question, it seems that Fejer's example cannot be represented by a graph. Here are my questions:

1.)What is the reason that the function cannot be represented by graph?

2.)Is there any function with the properties I mentioned that can be represented by graph?

3.)What is the intuitive reason that those functions have divergent Fourier series at some points?

I am aware that this question is a duplication of some already existing topics on MSE but none of the links I read give me a satisfactory answer. Also, could anyone give me a rough description of Fejer's function's behavior that explains why it can't be graphed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, that comment in that other thread does _not_ say it's impossible to represent the function by a graph. It says that drawing the graph on a computer is very slow. And it says that it is impossible to draw the graph _and_ see from looking at the graph why the series diverges.

Comment: Alright, then could you please explain why is it hard to draw the graph? Is it because of high variation or it has many fine details?

Comment: Yes. The function is continuous,  but it can't be _too_ continuous or the Fourier series would converge. So it's sort of continuous but not very, meaning that we need to plot a large number of points to  get a good picture. _And_ since the Fourier series _diverges_ we can't calculate the values by adding the Fourier series...

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $x$ and its Fourier series does not converge at $x$ or converges to something other than $f(x)$, then $f$ cannot be of bounded variation on any interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$, no matter how small you take $\epsilon$ to be. (This is because if it were of bounded variation on some such interval, the Fourier series *would* converge at $x$ to $f(x)$.) So you'd have to move your pen infinitely far to plot the graph over any such small interval!